# ASP.NET WebAPI can a POST receive parameters either from Uri or Body?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

1. POST `/auth` and write `serial=123` in body
2. POST `/auth?serial=123` with an empty body

Is it possible to accept these 2 kind of posts with one method?

At now I can only achieve it with 2 methods:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CheckSerial(string serial)
```

and

```
public class SerialViewModel
{
    public string serial { get; set; }
}
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CheckSerial(SerialViewModel sm)
```

I have noticed that in ASP.NET MVC5 it can be done with just one method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult auth(SerialViewModel check)
```

I can POST either  `/auth`(with `serial=123` in body) or `/auth?serial=123`.

But the WebAPI seems different?

--UPDATE--

Inspired by comment, I find a way like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult CheckSerial(SerialViewModel sm,[FromUri]string serial = null)
```

And I check both of them to get a value. But this is not quite convenient, especially if there are many parameters.

Comment: You can directly read them from both body and the url instead of supporting it that way

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this is an acceptable way, at least for me:

```
    public IHttpActionResult CheckSerial([FromBody] SerialViewModel checkBody, [FromUri] SerialViewModel checkUri)
    {
         return Json(new { status = (checkBody?.serial ?? checkUri?.serial ?? "")=="123"?"1":"0" });
    }
```